# Help with error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type

Tags: c++, vector

As the title states, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I've put together a test.cpp that's similar to this structure, and it works fine. Also, other than the vector problem, there's the other problem about 'protected', which isn't even in the code. I think 'protected' is a macro, so no telling what's there. I'm new to QT, so I'm likely "doing it wrong." That's certainly what the compiler's suggesting.

```
In file included from DrvCrystalfontz.cpp:8:
LCDText.h:28: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
LCDText.h:28: error: expected ';' before '<' token
LCDText.h:30: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
LCDText.h:30: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
LCDText.h:46: error: expected ':' before 'protected'
LCDText.h: In constructor 'LCDText::LCDText(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, QObject*)':
LCDText.h:33: error: expected '{' at end of input
scons: *** [DrvCrystalfontz.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Here's the code. I've numbered the lines noted in the error.

```
#ifndef __LCD_TEXT__
#define __LCD_TEXT__

#include <vector>
#include <QObject>

#include "LCDBase.h"
#include "WidgetText.h"
#include "WidgetBar.h"
#include "WidgetHistogram.h"
#include "WidgetIcon.h"
#include "WidgetBignums.h"
#include "WidgetGif.h"

class LCDText: public LCDBase, public virtual QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    protected:
        char *LayoutFB;
        char *DisplayFB;
        int GOTO_COST;
        int CHARS;
        int CHAR0;
        int LROWS;
        int LCOLS;
        int DROWS;
        int DCOLS;
        vector<vector<char *> > chars; // Line 28
        void (*TextRealWrite) (const int row, const int col, const char *data, const int len);
        void (*TextRealDefchar) (const int ascii, const vector<char *> matrix); // Line 30
    public:
        LCDText(int rows, int cols, int xres, int yres, int _goto, int chars,
            int char0, QObject *parent) : LCDBase(xres, yres), QObject(parent); // Line 33
        ~LCDText();
        void TextInit(int rows, int cols);
        void TextBlit(int row, int col, int  height, int width);
        void TextClear();
        void TextClearChars();
        void TextGreet();
        void TextDraw(WidgetText widget);
        void TextBarDraw(WidgetBar widget);
        void TextHistogramDraw(WidgetHistogram widget);
        void TextIconDraw(WidgetIcon widget);
        void TextBignumsDraw(WidgetBignums widget);
        void TextGifDraw(WidgetGif widget);
     public signals: // Line 46
         void SpecialCharChanged(int ch);
     public slots:
         void TextSpecialCharChanged(int ch);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Vector resides in the std namespace. You have to do one of the following:

Prepend the type with the namespace:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char *> > chars;
```

Tell the compiler you are using vector from the std namespace

```
using std::vector;
vector<vector<char *> > chars;
```

Or, tell the compiler you are using the std namespace, which will bring in everything (not recommended, see comments)

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Please, for the love of humanity, don't "using namespace XXX" in a header file.  You'll make every other programmer who comes across it cry.

Comment: Agreed, but you may as well tell people the options ;)

Comment: Well then include this option: using std::vector; I prefer it in the .cpp immediately after the include. Saves tying std:: all over the place *and* documents why the header was included (which is not always as obvious as in the case of vector).

Comment: c'mon - it's not that bad. **IF** you put it **inside** your class definition. Like any declaration it's scoped.

Answer (score 1):

every symbol declared in C++ standard library is part of the std namespace. In order to use these declarations you have to refer it by its full name. namely std::.
As MichaelM answered you should use std::vector instead of vector.
You can, however, use the following "using declarations":
1. `using std::vector;`
2. `using namespace std; // using namespace ...; is mostly discouraged as it causes a mass-import of symbols into the global namespace`

On any case, most of the time you should avoid using declaration in header files as it pollutes the global namespace for every user of your header.

good luck