# strange compile error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘set’ with no type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552170/help-with-error-iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-vector-with-no-type)

I'm using set in my code as follows:

```
#include <set> 

set<int> followers; //line 36
```

When i compile my code with g++, it prints the following error message:

```
myCode.cpp:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘set’ with no type  
myCode.cpp:36: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12):

You forgot to specify namespace: `std::set<int> followers;`.

What exactly happens is the following: since you didn't specified namespace compiler encounters an unknown symbol `set` and since it is it's first occurence it decides that it is a declaration: in C one could declare `int` variables without specifying type. C++ explicitly forbids that types of declarations, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `using namespace std` or just you can use `std::set<int>`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just import set identifier by

```
using std::set;
```

and then

```
set<int> something;
```